# How to map form fields to database object

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, forms, express

I wonder how these edit forms are built using modern frameworks like express with mongo db.

To clarify the question, I want to build an application that allows editing some of the fields of objects stored in Mongo. Each "form submit" should create a new instance of the objects with only the edited fields altered.

When populating the form, it is easy to retrieve the whole object and generate only the relevant fields in the view part of the application.

But when saving the form it is either required to retrieve the object again, then map "by hand" every form field into a field in the object, and finally save the new object into the database, or store beforehand all the fields of the object in the form as hidden fields and do some serialization.

As this is probably a common practice and both these methods a lacking I suspect a better technique available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com).

> Mongoose provides a straight-forward, schema-based solution to model your application data. It includes built-in type casting, validation, query building, business logic hooks and more, out of the box.

You can create Mongoose models, as described here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

For instance,

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
var Shirt = mongoose.model('Shirt', schema);
```

Then you can update your *Shirt* document instance by providing only the newly updated parameters, as described here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update

For instance,

```
Shirt.update({ name: 'New Name' }, { size: 'small' }, 
  function (err, raw) { 
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send "sparse" updates to Mongo where only a few fields get sent; You don't need to re-save the entire document. To do this you'd need to keep track of which fields have changed; Also known as "dirty" fields.

This is somewhat difficult to do in the traditional request-response round trip that you have with express since everything is stateless.

One solution would be to write a small frontend script that listened on your form fields for changes and saved a list of those field names into an `<input type="hidden">`. Then in your express app, check for that hidden field. If it exists, only process those fields. If it doesn't exist, re-save the entire document.